# Android Google Maps location permission

Tags: java, android, google-maps, emulation

I'm trying to get my current location.  According to the Android docs, I'm supposed to use this:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Unfortunately, the `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` part is not working for me.  I seem to have a Manifest class, and a 'permission' subclass.... but nothing beyond that.... so ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION cannot be found and I'm getting a "cannot resolve symbol ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" error.  I found a 'Manifest.java' file with the definition of permission... but nothing about ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.  It seems like I should add something to that 'Manifest.java' file, but there's a note at the top saying that the file was automatically generated and I shouldn't mess with it...

Comment: Try with `YourActivityName.this` instead of only `this` for e.g `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(TestingActivity.this)`.

Comment: try using android.permission .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this line:

```
import android.Manifest;
```

Comment: This worked!  import android.Manifest and then in the actual code:   Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Answer (score 0):

Try `android.permission` instead of `manifest.permission`.